# Phone app: what does the blue forbidden sign (with optional blue "A" in front) mean in the call log?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls, call-history, call-screening, app-icons

I have the following question concerning the Samsung Galaxy SIII:

When one taps `Phone -> Logs` it is possible to see the following icons:

- Incoming calls which were answered and received text messages
  (icon displays a green arrow pointing to the left)
  (clicking entry displays date and time call was received
  or text message was received and call duration for calls)
- Incoming calls which were not answered
  (icon displays a white arrow bouncing to the left off a red phone receiver)
  (clicking entry displays date and time call was received
  and displays the text "Missed")
- Outgoing calls
  (icon displays an orange arrow pointing to the right)
  (android phone app does not differentiate outgoing calls which were answered
  from outgoing calls which were not answered, but clicking on the entry displays
  call duration for calls which were answered or the text "Canceled" for calls
  which were not answered)

However, I am not sure what the following mean in the Phone application:

- icon displays blue circle with diagonal line through it
  (clicking on this entry displays a date and time and the text "Canceled")
- icon displays blue circle with diagonal line through it
  with blue uppercase "A" in front of it
  (clicking on this entry displays a date and time and the text "Canceled")

What is the difference between these two icons?

Thanks.

The five different possible icons I mentioned appear in the following screenshot (contact names and phone numbers scribbled-out, click to enlarge):

[image: Phone app Log icons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The icon that displays a blue circle with diagonal line through it in the Phone app's Log tab appears when the user receives a call and manually rejects it with a swipe when the phone rings. As soon as the user swipes to reject the call, the caller will hear the tone of the phone call change from a ringing signal to a busy signal.
- The icon that displays a blue circle with diagonal line through it and a blue "A" in front of it in the Phone app's Log tab appears when the user receives a call but the caller has been added to the reject list from the Contacts app. In this case the caller will never hear a ringing signal and will hear a busy signal as soon as the call is made, and the receiving party will not hear the phone ringing since the contact was added to the reject list of course. **The blue A in front of the blue circle with a diagonal line through it is most likely understood to be the first letter of the word *autorejected*.**

Regards.

Comment: Just now 'The blue A in front of the blue circle with a diagonal line through it' happened to me.  I read your answers and assumed the person I was in contact with added me to autoreject list.  Please do not come to conclusions that technology always works as we predict it to work.  The person was in a government building which blocked all his calls.  He had to contact his boss and realized his phone was not working. I assumed he put me on autoreject list, when in fact, the building he was in must have some controlled signalling system setup.